# Kendo UI grid select a row onload

Tags: kendo-grid

I have a list of users, **List of User binded to a grid.** I have a currently logged in user information in **ViewData[User]**. 
What I want is if a **grid contains a user which is in ViewData, I want that user to be selected as soon as grid loads data. How can I do this validation? How can I get currently selected row ?**

```cs
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(KendoGridAjaxBinding.Models.User)()  
 .Name("grid")  
 .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource   .Ajax()  
 .Read(read => read.Action("User_Read", "Home"))       
 .Columns(columns => {
    columns.Bound(user=> user.UserID);   
    columns.Bound(user=> user.UserName);   
    columns.Bound(user=> user.City);  
  ).Pageable().Sortable())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pre select a row you can try with this code in the grid:

```
.RowAction(row => 
        {
            if (condition)
            {
                row.HtmlAttributes["class"] = "k-state-selected";
            }
        })
```

And to get the selected row you can call a JavaScript function like this if you are editing:

```
function editItem(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
            //the dataItem will be the user model
        }
```

or take a look at this post of [Kendo](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-web/grid/grid-select.aspx)